# Trouble setting up the spotify API, ./confure not working (Creating project folders and files)

Tags: bash, spotify

I'm trying to work with the spotify API, so I started [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/), which is the quick start guide. I'm on the Create a Project Folder and Files step. Everything before that works. I already have node downloaded. I was on [This website](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples)
which was linked from the spotify guide, so I tried the steps linked on [this site](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814). and every time I get to ./configure, it doesn't work and says "./configure: No such file or directory". I'm not good with these types of things, so some advice about whether or not I'm doing the right thing and how to fix it would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those scripts theres:

```
git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure --prefix=~/local
```

So it git clones the node repository, `cd` into it, and tries to run `configure` script from within the directory.

From [the github node repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive):

```
This repository is an archive of Node.js before the move to nodejs/node.
```

Change the git url to `https://github.com/nodejs/node`.

Comment: When I run the /configure, it starts with "which: no python2.7 in" and then what seems to be all of my file paths, then says "which: no python2 in" and then file paths, and ends with "./configure: line 3: exec: python: not found". I'm guessing my python file is in the wrong place? I tried to change the PATH but I can only run things like "pip install" In a specific directory (I know python is installed, I use it frequently" but I use python3. Do I need to change the file path or install python 2?

Comment: Inspect the sources in https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/configure . You have to install python to build nodejs. Your whole approach is just strange. Just install nodejs and npm on your pc, don't fall back to cloning the source code and compiling it yourself. Why are you doing it? What linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm not very good with this kind of stuff, I'm just following the spotify guides as best as I understand. I already downloaded the newest version of nodejs and npm, can I just skip this step then? Where do I need to continue? Can I move on to the "Using your own credentials" part I linked earlier?

Comment: What linux distribution are you using? Debian? Ubuntu? Opensuse? Archlinux? Just install nodejs using your systems package manager, like `sudo apt install nodejs npm`

Comment: I'm just on windows, I'm pretty sure I have them both installed now